# Undefined symbol error when using macro (Keil)

Tags: assembly, macros, 8051, keil

I'm having some problems with MACROs in 8051 assembler (using Keil uVision 5.11).

I'm getting error:

```
Build target 'Target 1'
assembling MAIN.a51...
MAIN.a51(62): error A45: UNDEFINED SYMBOL (PASS-2)
MAIN.a51(67): error A45: UNDEFINED SYMBOL (PASS-2)
MAIN.a51(72): error A45: UNDEFINED SYMBOL (PASS-2)
MAIN.a51(76): error A45: UNDEFINED SYMBOL (PASS-2)
MAIN.a51(89): error A45: UNDEFINED SYMBOL (PASS-2)
MAIN.a51(107): error A45: UNDEFINED SYMBOL (PASS-2)
Target not created.
```

Here's my code (in it's entirety, as when I tried to make a shortened example, the error did not happen).

```
; UART
; 0.000001085 s ... NOP
; 1ms ... 922 NOPs
; 1 bit ... 96 NOPs
; Half bit ... 48 NOPs

UART_OUT equ P2.0
UART_CLK equ P2.1

DSEG at 30h


; Pomocne promenne
I: DS  1
J: DS  1
K: DS  1



; 1 ms delay
M_WAIT_1MS MACRO
    MOV  A,#229
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    CALL wait_a4_cycles 
ENDM




; 1 bit time delay
M_WAIT_BIT MACRO
    MOV  A,#24
    NOP
    CALL wait_a4_cycles 
ENDM




; half bit time delay
M_WAIT_HALF_BIT MACRO
    MOV  A,#12
    NOP
    CALL fn_wait_a4_cycles  
ENDM




CSEG at 00000h

    MOV  SP,#70H

    SETB UART_OUT
    SETB UART_CLK

; Hlavni smycka
main:
        M_WAIT_1MS    ; *ERROR HERE*

        MOV A,#'A'
        CALL fn_uart_send_byte

        M_WAIT_1MS    ; *ERROR HERE*

        MOV A,#'H'
        CALL fn_uart_send_byte

        M_WAIT_1MS    ; *ERROR HERE*

        MOV A,#'O'
        CALL fn_uart_send_byte
        M_WAIT_1MS    ; *ERROR HERE*

        MOV A,#'J'
        CALL fn_uart_send_byte  
    JMP main


; Send byte in A over "UART"
fn_uart_send_byte:
    MOV  K,A                                ; store in tmp var
    MOV  J,#8                               ; bit counter

    CLR  UART_OUT                           ; start bit
    M_WAIT_BIT

fusb_1:                                     ; loop over the bits
        XCH  A,K                            ; K -> A
        RRC  A                              ; Rotate A through carry
        MOV  UART_OUT,C                     ; Carry to output
        XCH  A,K                            ; A -> K

        M_WAIT_HALF_BIT                     ; halfbit delay *NO ERROR HERE!?*

        CLR UART_CLK                        ; Clock pulse
        SETB UART_CLK   

        M_WAIT_HALF_BIT                     ; halfbit delay *ALSO NO ERROR*

    DJNZ J,fusb_1                           ; Repeat if there's more bits

    CLR  UART_OUT                           ; stop bit
    M_WAIT_BIT      ; *ERROR HERE*
    SETB UART_OUT

    RET                                     ; Return from routine



; DELAY A*4 "NOP"s (excluding CALL)
fn_wait_a4_cycles:
    NOP                                     ; 1
    NOP                                     ; 1
    NOP                                     ; 1
    PUSH I                                  ; 2   Preserve original I
    CLR  C                                  ; 1   Clear Carry
    SUBB A,#3                               ; 1   overhead = 3*4 = 12  Subtract fn overhead from requested count
    MOV  I,A                                ; 1   Store result in I

fwa4c_1:                                    ; Waiting loop of length 4 NOPs
        NOP 
        NOP
    DJNZ I,fwa4c_1                          ; 2

    POP  I                                  ; 2   Restore original I
    RET                                     ; 2   Return

END
```

Comment: NEVERMIND I FOUND THE ERROR

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I used undefined label in the macros for calling - and Keil, stupid as those tools usually are, did not mark the correct location of the error.